# MS Project VBA coding to include expiration date

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

Can I add code to a macro in MSP2010 so that it will not run after a specified date?

The code I have tried is this:

```
Dim expire As Date


expire = 1 / 8 / 2015


If activeproject.currentdate.value > expire Then
    MsgBox ("This macro is no longer accessible, please contact your PMO")
    Exit Sub
End If


'actual macro


End Sub
```

The intention is to protect my work once I have left an organisation.

Comment: Why would you want some business functionality to be unavailable after you have left?

Comment: These are a number of schedule checkers and reporting tools that I have been developing over time that I would not want clients to continue to access if my company was no longer engaged to provide planning support.

Comment: Shouldn't you just uninstall them then?

Comment: I anticipate sharing several of the tools with members of the team to help them with their updating. Once they have been circulated I doubt I would be able to remove all installations.

Comment: 1) What are the terms of your contract? Most contracts grant permanent rights to any code developed during the contract. (2) It seems trivial for the customer to override this code - are you doing eyewash security?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace What is "eyewash security"? Google hasn't heard of it!

Comment: Eyewash security is like security theatre or velvet rope security. Effectively it means that you have a very low assurance security implementation. If you're writing code to prevent the customer from doing something, but the customer has access to that code and can rewrite it, then you have asserted security, but not enforced it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make an assumption that you don't have an agreement with the other party to have access to your IP. Generally anything developed by you on their time is theirs, but maybe these are macros you built yourself on your own time.

1. Write a plugin. Your killswitch code will work, and it would be harder for them to just go in and comment it back out.
2. Keep your code in project file on a shared drive, and access it from the other file by using:

   ```
   Application.Run "path/to/file.mpp!secret_code"
   ```
3. Negotiate a royalty free runtime license for a couple bucks, (or even free) and use them as a reference for your next contract.

Breaking people's stuff isn't going to win you any friends, and depending on your jurisdiction this type of logic bomb may actually be illegal.